# Как настрить свой стабильный composer пакет?

Tags: php, composer

Есть композер проект:

```json
{
  "name": "carriongrow/uploader",
  "description": "Package of uploads",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Anatoliy Snegovskiy",
      "email": "CarrionGrow@Gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.3.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "james-heinrich/getid3": "^1.9"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"CarrionGrow\\Uploader\\": "src/"},
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["/test/"]
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

https://github.com/AnatolySnegovskiy/uploader

https://packagist.org/packages/carriongrow/uploader

При попытке загрузить его:

```sh
composer require carriongrow/uploader
```

получаю:

> Could not find a version of package carriongrow/uploader matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.

Перепробовал уже всё, теги естественно стоят, пакет обновлял. Убирал, добавлял параметры `"minimum-stability": "dev"`, описывал через экстру ветку — ничего не помогает, постоянно одно и тоже.

У меня есть ещё один пустой тестовый проект композера, он заходит на ура без каких либо проблем, сверял с ним, все тоже самое по сути. Было предположение, что проблема заключается в том что я использую внутри другой ещё пакет, убирал его, но это ни к чему не привело, всё та же ошибка, что нет стабильной версии пакета. Хотя сделаны теги проведены релизы.

Comment: Кэш очистить + подождать немного. Всё норм ставится: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUgkL.png

Comment: Не че не пойму вообще, почистил кеши, сделал новый проект туда цепляю свой пакет и точно таже проблема. Че происходит O_o

Comment: Поставил композер второй версии и все заработало

Comment: Напишите сами ответ, когда можно будет.

Answer (score 2):

Так и не понял в чем была проблема, но после обновления композера на 2 версию проблема решилась. При том что на сервере стоит первая версия и там проблемы не было. По всей видимости это были проблемы локального кеша композера.

Comment: Возможно кэш не чистился, так как прав нет каких-либо ...